# How to create an ordered chain linked to a node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a set of `HeadNodes` which has field id and I have a set of `TailNodes` which are not related to each other and to `HeadNodes` and have fields `id` and  `date` in `milliseconds`.

I want to write the query which takes:

`Match (p: TailNodes) where not (p)-[:RELATED_TO]->()`

that are not joined to `HeadNode` directly or through another `TailNodes` take their id number and look though `HeadNodes` for this id. When I found it (it's guaranteed to be there) I looked for a place to put it (in order of date time).

For example:

we have 1 `HeadNode{id: 1}` and 3 `TailNodes: {id: 1, datetime: 111}`, `{id: 1, datetime: 115}`, and `{id: 1, datetime: 113}` without any relationships.

At first step it takes first `TailNode {id: 1, datetime: 111}` and creates a relationship:
`(head:HeadNode{id: 1})<-[:RELATED_TO]-(tail:TainNodes{id:1, datetime:111})`

At second step it takes second `Tailnode` and finds out that `115` is greater than `111`, so it deletes the previous relationship and creates 2 new relationships, and a chain that looks like this:

```
(head:HeadNode{id: 1})<-[:RELATED_TO]-(tail1:TainNodes{id:1, datetime:115})<-[:RELATED_TO]-(tail2:TainNodes{id:1, datetime:111})
```

At third step it founds out that `113` is greater than `111` but lesser than `115` and deletes relationship between `datetime:115 and datetime:111`; and then creates two new relationships finally getting the following:

```
(head:HeadNode{id: 1})<-[:RELATED_TO]-(tail1:TainNodes{id:1, datetime:115})<-[:RELATED_TO]-(tail2:TainNodes{id:1, datetime:113})<-[:RELATED_TO]-(tail3:TainNodes{id:1, datetime:111})
```

I hope it was clear explanation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would a simpler way of saying this be that you want all of your tail nodes connected to the head node, in DESCENDING order of datetime?

Comment: so do the tail nodes just appear from time to time? i.e. if they were all there at once i could create the linked list of tails but later on i might need to break the link and insert new ones as they appear?

Comment: Tail nodes appear from time to time and i need a query to put them in correct place in chain when it happends. I'm doing it now with Java, but still trying to solve this problem using only sypher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, first cut... out of time to create a more robust example but will take another shot later.

I started with a case where there were already nodes in teh list

```
H<--(T {dt:112})<--(T {dt:114})
```

I realize i create these in ascending order and not descending order too.

```
// match the orphaned tail nodes floating around
match (p:Tail)
where not(p-->())
with p  
// match the strand with the same name and the tail nodes that are connected
// where one datetime (dt) is greater and one is less than my orphaned tail nodes
match (t1:Tail)<-[r:RELATED_TO]-(t2:Tail)
where t1.name = p.name
  and t2.name = p.name
  and t1.dt < p.dt
  and t2.dt > p.dt
// break the relationship between the two nodes i want to insert between
delete r
// create new relationships from the orphan to the two previously connected tails
with t1, t2, p
create p-[:RELATED_TO]->t1
create t2-[:RELATED_TO]->p
return *
```

The case just needs to be extended for a tailless head and an orphan with a datetime greater than the last tail (i.e not in between two existing).

Comment: Thank you. I've done it in Java, but it shows a terrible executing time. So i'm going to try to fix it with cypher